# Should I store my uncooked marinated chicken wings in the freezer?

Tags: chicken, freezing, storage

Today I have marinated lots of chicken wings.  I have to store three-fourths of these in the freezer. I am wondering whether I should keep these uncooked or half cooked. I will keep these in zipper bags for two or three weeks.

I previously kept some half cooked marinated wings and found that was good to defrost.  But, I am not sure about the taste.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Please note that if you have further information to add to your question, you can use the "Edit" option to update.  I've flagged the answer that you added since it doesn't actually address the question, and I'm also going to edit your question to add the same information.

Answer (score 1):

From a flavor standpoint, the preparation of the wings isn't likely to affect how well they taste after being defrosted.  I think you're most likely to notice a difference in texture.

Although you didn't ask about safety, it's very important that you do cook the wings fully after they're thawed, even if you've par-cooked them previously.  If the meat is at all raw, there's a possibility that any bacteria present will continue to reproduce and quickly re-colonize the cooked portions.  Unless they're cooled from the initial cooking and frozen very quickly, they could stay long enough in the so-called ["danger zone"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat) to cause concern.

So, given that you need to cook them fully, partially cooking doesn't gain you anything - you're just damaging (via cooking) some of the meat.  That will make the wings drier than they would be otherwise.  For the best texture, keep them raw before freezing and cook them completely after being defrosted.